# Back button & Iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, browser-history

I have a link which opens up a Jquery UI Dialog containing an iframe. When I click the back button in the browser it cycles through the iframes history. I want it to go back in the parent windows history. How would I do this?

I'm aware there are similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find any which answer my question.

Comment: When you say "back button" do you mean the browsers back button, an element in the iFrame HTML, or some other kind of back button?

Comment: @Seth The browsers back button

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're stuck (with that behavior, I mean). You must be having links to other pages within that IFRAME? I wonder why such setup (dialog > iframe that changes URL)? Usually we popup dialogs with some forms. Can that iframe be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by returning false on all links inside the iframe. I realize this isn't really a solution for most people looking at this problem but it works perfectly for me.